# Google location settings not working as exptected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, localization, geolocation

I am working with the google features to enable and disable location for the user,  my main goal is, i enter the camera activity and it asks the user if he clicks cancel it goes back to the previous activity if everything fine it let the user take the photo.

**This is my code:**

```
`public class GoogleLocation extends Activity {
private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 5 ;

public static void displayLocationSettingsRequest(final Context context) {

    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    googleApiClient.connect();

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);


    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    Log.i("location", "All location settings are satisfied.");
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    Log.i("location", "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to upgrade location settings ");
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                        // in onActivityResult().
                        Log.d("HELLO2","HELLO2");
                        status.startResolutionForResult((Activity) context, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.i("location", "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.i("location", "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("requestCode",String.valueOf(requestCode));
    Log.d("resultCode",String.valueOf(resultCode));
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
        Log.d("ENTERED","ENTERED");
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Log.d("ENTERED","ENTERED");
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

}
`
i thaught that i can controll the dialog options 'ok' and 'cancel' with the onactivityresult, but as you guys can see inside the onactivity result i have 2 Log.d this just get fired when i pres the 'x' from the camera to close the camera, what is going on? i need to control the dialog but it is not working :/.

Any tip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this function to enable location in high accuracy

```
public static void checkLocationSettings(final Activity context){

    if(!LocationUtil.isLocationServicesAvailable(context)){

        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        Log.e(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to upgrade location settings ");

                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(context, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

use this function to check location is enabled with high accuracy

```
public static boolean isLocationServicesAvailable(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    boolean isAvailable = false;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        isAvailable = (locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF && locationMode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

if the user hit ok then the location will enable with high accuracy. else it will stay in the current state. if the location is already enabled and not in high accuracy, then it also the prompt will come to change location mode to high accuracy.